# Loading trained Tensorflow model into estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

Say that I have trained a Tensorflow Estimator:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
  model_fn=model_fn,
  model_dir=MODEL_DIR,
  config=some_config)
```

And I fit it to some train data:

```
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=None)
```

The idea is that a model is fit to my MODEL_DIR. This folder contains a checkpoint and several files of `.meta` and `.index`.

This works perfectly. I want to do some predictions using my functions:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.Estimator(
  model_fn=model_fn,
  model_dir=MODEL_DIR,
  config=some_config)

predictions = estimator.predict(input_fn=input_fn_test)
```

My solution works perfectly but there is one big disadvantage: you need to know model_fn, which is my model defined in Python. But if I change the model by adding a dense layer in my Python code, this model is incorrect for the saved data in MODEL_DIR, leading to incorrect results:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key xxxx/dense/kernel not found in checkpoint
```

How do I cope with this? How can I load my model / estimator such that I can make predictions on some new data? How can I load model_fn or the estimator from MODEL_DIR?

Answer (score 1):

## Avoiding a bad restoration

Restoring a model's state from a checkpoint only works if the model and checkpoint are compatible. For example, suppose you trained a `DNNClassifier` Estimator containing two hidden layers, each having 10 nodes:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[10, 10],
    n_classes=3,
    model_dir='models/iris')

classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda:train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, batch_size=100),
        steps=200)
```

After training (and, therefore, after creating checkpoints in `models/iris`), imagine that you changed the number of neurons in each hidden layer from 10 to 20 and then attempted to retrain the model:

```
classifier2 = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[20, 20],  # Change the number of neurons in the model.
    n_classes=3,
    model_dir='models/iris')

classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda:train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, batch_size=100),
        steps=200)
```

Since the state in the checkpoint is incompatible with the model described in `classifier2`, retraining fails with the following error:

```
...
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): tensor_name =
dnn/hiddenlayer_1/bias/t_0/Adagrad; shape in shape_and_slice spec [10]
does not match the shape stored in checkpoint: [20]
```

To run experiments in which you train and compare slightly different versions of a model, save a copy of the code that created each `model_dir`, possibly by creating a separate git branch for each version. This separation will keep your checkpoints recoverable.

copy from tensorflow checkpoints doc.

https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/checkpoints

hope that can help you.

Comment: Is there a reason why the original model is not stored in a more generic format? I understand that your solution requires to store the python code for each model, but that feels a bit hacky

Comment: your code build the model structure(i.e. layer count, neuron count of each layer), if your model structure is changed, your backup model can't match the model, it will raise a error. so each structure(python code) will link a backup model.